# EXTJS 4 how to validate radio group?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Before I dive into source code and hack it.
I set allowBlank: false on radio group. I would like to mark it if none of the radio is selected. What method to override ?

Regards
Armando

Answer (score 0):

just override validate method and do the magic there.

```
.field-container-error-border {
    background-image: url(../ext4/extjs/ext-4_2_1/resources/ext-theme-gray/images/grid/invalid_line.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c30 !important;
}
```

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.RadioGroup, {
  validate: function() {
    let isValid = this.callParent();
    let el = Ext.dom.Element.get(this.el.query('.x-table-plain')[0]);
    if (!isValid) {
      el.addCls('field-container-error-border');
    } else {
      el.removeCls('field-container-error-border');
    }
    return isValid;
  },
});
```